# Retrieve first N objects from two or more groups

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

### Background info:

Our web application (a sort of social network) lets users add *galleries* and *documents* to the system. Galleries are represented by a **Gallery** class and mapped with an appropriate hibernate mapping - same goes for the documents. Both classes contain a *creationDate* field.

### The problem

Implementing a *News* system (similar to Facebook's Home) i need to be able to retrieve the first **N** results from **both** the classes at the same time (ordered by *creationDate*).

Using hibernate **Criteria** i well know how to get the first N results from each class, but this is not what i'm looking for. I could do that and then sort them but it doesn't seem very efficient.

### Example:

Having:

```
Gallery 1 - 12/09/13 10:10
Gallery 2 - 12/09/13 09:10
Gallery 3 - 12/09/13 08:20
Gallery 4 - 12/09/13 08:10
```

and

```
Document 1 - 12/09/13 08:25
Document 2 - 12/09/13 07:10
Document 3 - 12/09/13 06:15
Document 4 - 12/09/13 05:10
```

Asking for the first **4** would give:

```
Gallery 1 - 12/09/13 10:10
Gallery 2 - 12/09/13 09:10
Document 1 - 12/09/13 08:25
Gallery 3 - 12/09/13 08:20
```

**How would you implement something like this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One strategy I have used for this type of scenario is to create a view that unions the two tables.

So lets say they are stored in the database like:

```
create table GALLERY(
    GALLERY_ID INT,
    NAME VARCHAR2(20),
    CREATION_DT
);

create table DOCUMENT(
    GALLERY_ID INT,
    NAME VARCHAR2(20),
    CREATION_DT
);
```

The view would look something like (Psuedo Code):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_NEWS as 
select 
   GALLERY_ID as NEWS_ID
   NAME,
   CREATION_DT,
   'GALLERY' as TYPE
from GALLERY
UNION
select 
   DOCUMENT_ID as NEWS_ID
   NAME,
   CREATION_DT,
   'DOCUMENT' as TYPE
from DOCUMENT
```

Now make this a class/entity in your application and wire appropriately with Hibernate.  In ORMs views map just like tables, the only difference being you cannot insert to views unless you establish some triggers (which I wouldn't recommend).  It seems as if this functionality would be read only anyway so that shouldn't be an issue.  Obviously you do not want to union the complete set of tables and may need to add a where clause that limits the view to a particular user and possibly date range.

Comment: This seems very interesting and appropriate. The view would be created indipendently in sql, outside of the wepApp (using tools as PgAdmin)?

Comment: @Enoon Yes the view would be created within the database, independent of the application.  You would use your choice of DBMS tools

Comment: To be clear: after obtaining a list of V_NEWS items i'll have to retrieve the rest of the class data (for example documents also hold a description) by querying by id in the usual way? Or you suggest to include all relevant data directly in the view?

Comment: @Enoon If there are elements common between both classes include them in the view, otherwise query them by id as you suggested.